# Summing a exponential series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

What is the appropriate way to simplify such an expression.
i am unsure of how to use the series i know to apply to this situation

$$\sum_{L=0}^{M}s^{L}L^{2}$$

do i modify such a series as power series, or is there a more efficient series to use here?

thank you very much!!

Comment: If $M$ were $\infty$, then there is a power-series-based method to simplify the sum. Would it help to have that explained? Or do you need $M$ to be finite?

Comment: M is a number that isnt infiniti. thank you for reply, but how to solve for M not infiniti?

Comment: out of being curious suppose $\sum_{L=0}^{M}s^{L}L$ would the same method follow

Comment: The method I've used in my answer can apply to a sum where the terms are $s^LL^k$, where $k$ is an integer. Even if $k$ is negative, then you just have to make the inside look like an integral rather than a derivative. (However, executing the integral at the end will be harder than executing the derivative.) So yes, this method works with $k=1$ too.

Comment: @ alex.jordan : An algebraic explanation to your method is one basis chang on $\mathbb R[X]$. We try express the canonical basis $(1,X,X^2,...)$ with the basis : $(1,X,X(X-1),X(X-1)(X-2), ...à$ and this expression gives a simple way to calculate generalized expression ...

Comment: @Mohamed Thanks - I figured OP would want a calculus-only kind of answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make the inner expression look like a derivative:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{L=0}^M\left(Ls^{L-1}\right)sL & =s\sum_{L=0}^M\left(\partial_ss^L\right)L\\
& =s\partial_s\sum_{L=0}^Ms^LL\\
& =s\partial_s\sum_{L=0}^M\left(Ls^{L-1}\right)s\\
& =s\partial_s\left(s\sum_{L=0}^M\left(Ls^{L-1}\right)\right)\\
& =s\partial_s\left(s\sum_{L=0}^M\partial_ss^L\right)\\
& =s\partial_s\left(s\partial_s\sum_{L=0}^Ms^L\right)\\
& =s\partial_s\left(s\partial_s\frac{s^{M+1}-1}{s-1}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Now just take it from here, simplifying from the inside out.

Answer (score 4):

Write : $L^2=L(L-1)+L$  and  use  derivative. For $ L \geq 2$ :
$$L^2 s^L = s^2L(L-1)s^{L-2}+ s Ls^{L-1}= s^2(s^L)'' + s (s^L)'$$
We get :
$$\sum_{L=0}^M L^2s^L=0^2+1^2 s + s^2 \left(\sum_{L=2}^{M} s^L \right)''+s \left(\sum_{L=2}^{M} s^L \right)'$$

Comment: $L$ is the index in your sum, so I think you must means something else for the first two terms of your left-hand side.

Comment: Oops I meant right-hand side :)

Comment: @ alex.jordan Thank you very much.I mean :$0^2 s^0  + 1^2 s^1$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $L^2 = L(L-1)+L. $ Then,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{L=0}^{M} { L^2 s^L } &= \sum_{L=0}^{M} {L(L-1)s^L} + \sum_{L=0}^{M} {Ls^L}\\
&=s^2 \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2} \sum_{L=0}^{M}{s^L} + s \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\sum_{L=0}^{M} {s^L}\\
\end{align}$$

You can find formulas for the summations with detailed descriptions of their derivations by searching for ["Geometric Progression."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)